# Preserving data in a fetch request in node js

Tags: node.js, rest, telegram-bot, node-fetch

Oilà,
I'm a beginner with nodejs and I am using it to create a telegram bot. This is my code:

```
const Geolocation = (req) => {
        var address = "15 Freedom Way, Jersey City, NJ 07305, United States";
        let msg = "";

        let nodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');
        let param = {
            provider: 'openstreetmap'
        };
        let geoCoder = nodeGeocoder(param);
        geoCoder.geocode(address)
            .then((res) => {
                msg = res[0].streetName;

            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

        console.log(msg);

        return UTILS.formatDialogflowResponse(
            msg,
            []
        );
    }
```

I would like it to keep the `streetName` so that I can send it as a return response in `UTILS.formatDialogflowResponse`

I tried to write to a file and then read it just before sending, but every time it tends to first read the file, thus creating an error, and then write on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first learn about `Promise` and `async await` in Nodejs.

For short, you can try this

```
const Geolocation = async (req) => {
var address="15 Freedom Way, Jersey City, NJ 07305, United States";
let msg="";

let nodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');
let param = {
  provider: 'openstreetmap'
};

let geoCoder = nodeGeocoder(param);
await geoCoder.geocode(address)
  .then((res)=> {
    msg=res[0].streetName;
    
})
.catch((err)=> {
  console.log(err);
});

console.log(msg);

return UTILS.formatDialogflowResponse(
    msg,
    []
);}
```